# How to create a form at the front end and save data in entities

Tags: php, magento2

I created a module in path app/code/Smartshore/Subscription

I want to create a route that displays a form and save data in it. I have the code but I don't know what is missing: Please see the below code:

Smartshore/Subscription/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="subscription" frontName="subscription">
            <module name="Smartshore_Subscription" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Smartshore/Subscription/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Smartshore\Subscription\Controller\Index;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends Action
{   
    /** @var  \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
                                \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Subscription Index, shows a list of subscriptions
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

Smartshore/Subscription/Controller/Index/Add.php

```
<?php

namespace Smartshore\Subscription\Controller;


use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Add extends Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $pageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Smartshore/Subscription/Controller/Index/Result.php

```
<?php

namespace Smartshore\Subscription\Controller;


use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Result extends Action
{
    /** @var PageFactory $resultPageFactory */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Result constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $pageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $pageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * The controller action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $number = $this->getRequest()->getParam('number');

        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        /** @var Messages $messageBlock */
        $messageBlock = $resultPage->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages',
            'answer'
        );
        if (is_numeric($number)) {
            $messageBlock->addSuccess($number . ' times 2 is ' . ($number * 2));
        }else{
            $messageBlock->addError('You didn\'t enter a number!');
        }

        $resultPage->getLayout()->setChild(
            'content',
            $messageBlock->getNameInLayout(),
            'answer_alias'
        );

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Smartshore/Subscription/view/frontend/layout/subscription_index_add.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>New Subscription</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="subscriptionform.add" template="Smartshore_Subscription::form.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Smartshore/Subscription/view/frontend/layout/subscription_index_result.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Result</title>
    </head>
</page>
```

I have other files as well. But I have shown here files respect to my form and its submission.

When I enter `/subscription/index/add` I get No route found.

What is the problem?

Comment: Try with subscription/add and check is it open or not ? also check when you pass subscription what happen ?

Comment: when i pass /subscription, my Controller/Index/Index.php runs and shows a list of subscriptions. When I hit /subscription/add  404 page comes

Answer (score 1):

Check namespaces in Add and Result files/classes. It should be `namespace Smartshore\Subscription\Controller\Index`